# how to implement server side events with spring mvc for group chat

Tags: spring-mvc, messaging, server-sent-events

I am implementing topic based chat messaging system as part of larger application where certain group(there are multiple groups) members can drop messages on a topic. only group members should receive these messages. I am going to use spring mvc based REST controller as general REST endpoints to serve both mobile devices and web users.

Currently, I know that I can use push notifications for Android and ios based devices and update the group about new messages being posted. however, I am more concerned about how I am going to handle things at server side.
I am thinking of using server side events mechanism to push messages to other group members. is it right way to do so?

if yes, other question is about how to design this. suppose a group member creates a message and sends it. Following things would happen.

At server side, handler Rest controller would process the message by storing in database and open a JMS connection to publish this message.some listener (what type of class this could be?) should receive this message and should be able to push the messages to say 5 other group members. how do I design this?
as I understand that, all 5 group members must have browser open an Eventsource based connection to keep listening to all events(and associated data) coming from server. 
How can I use messaging (or some other appropriate mechanism) and server side events(REST controller) to work together at server side and push messages to only group members?

and how do I send messages to targeted members from my REST controller which is going to stream the events to listening clients?

thanks you for your patience while reading such a long query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you had better use a real-time web application framework like [Cettia](http://cettia.io/) to focus your business logic without unnecessary ties to low-level details.

As an one of low-level details, Server-Sent Events is just yet another HTTP streaming technique which is one of traditional technologies for Comet. The HTTP streaming doesn't work if user uses proxy which doesn't delegate each response chunk until some whole response ends. For such user, you should use HTTP long polling which is also one of such technologies but is worse than streaming in terms of performance. All these technologies provide just one-way connection so you need to do more work to make them pseudo full-duplex to write chat app. Such issues are well explained in [RFC 6202](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6202). As you may have heard, WebSocket provides full-duplex connection but in the real world, many coporate proxies, firewalls and antivirus softwares blocks it for some reason. At least to use reliable full duplex connection, you should use well-made frameworks. For example, in Cettia, client tries various transports including listed ones in performance order internally and provides really a working full-duplex connection as a result.

To deal with a group of socket like your 5 group members, you should use a kind of topic concept as you already pointed. In Cettia, [tag](http://cettia.io/projects/cettia-java-server/1.0.0-Alpha1/reference/#tagging) provides such features. For example, you can tag some socket i.e. `socket.tag("group1")` and deal with tagged sockets in a comfortable way e.g. `server.byTag("group1").send("chat", "welcome")`. With some efforts for clustering, you can publish such operation to all nodes in the cluster (using JMS, Hazelcast or any pub-sub system) so that any socket tagged with `group1` in any server will send `chat` event whose data is `welcome` by that published operation. Also what if some user is disconnected for a little while i.e. switching wifi to 3g and some other user sends some message to that user? You need a way to resend such messages when that user connects again. (In Cettia, a feature to deal with such problem is on the roadmap) As you can see, a lot of features are needed to write a just simple real-time webapp.

Here's working examples.

- [Servlet 3 and Java WebSocket API 1](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-examples/tree/master/archetype/cettia-java-server/platform/servlet3-jwa1) as Spring MVC is built on Servlet.
- [JMS 2](https://github.com/cettia/cettia-examples/tree/master/archetype/cettia-java-server/clustering/jms2) for scaling using JMS.

As I'm the author of Cettia, I gave you Cettia examples but such features are common to such frameworks so that you are likely to find other projects have supported them in their own way similarly.

Comment: Thanks Kim. I will try your framework and see if I can use this.